# Помогите с формулой. Как ее раcсчитать php?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Есть формула

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

**Как ее расcчитать в php?**

Comment: простите за такой вопрос, конечно, но в чем именно проблема?

Comment: Операции умножения и возведения в степень доступны в любом языке программирования. Почему вы не обратились к документации и не попытались написать код самостоятельно? Или у вас возникли какие-то проблемы/ошибки при расчетах? Если так, покажите нам что конкретно у вас не получилось.

Comment: Я просто не пойму как это расписать в php.

Comment: Смахивает на домашнее задание. Откройте-ка http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.arithmetic.php, изучите. А потом найдите, что делает функция pow

Comment: Евгений, совсем-что ли! Я просто не знаю как это делается в php - все! свои домыслы оставляй при себе!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение такое:

```
$x = 100;
$y = 3;
$h = 2;
$out = round($x*(pow(1.8, $h*$y)),2);
echo $out; // выводит 3401.22
```

Прочитайте про возведение в степень [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pow.php), все действия стандартные.